# `echohl` not highligthing with custom color, but its working with the defaults

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, neovim

in my `init.vim` (.vimrc) file i have this:

```
hi TerminalGreenColor guifg=#6bd676

function! EchoInitVimReloadedSuccessfully()
    echon " -- [ "
    echohl Identifier
    echon "init.vim"
    echohl None
    echon " ] reloaded "
    echohl TerminalGreenColor
    echon "successfully"
    echohl None
    echon " -- "
endfunction


" reload vim with init.vim
nnoremap <C-R> :source $init_vim_path<CR> :call EchoInitVimReloadedSuccessfully()<CR>
```

when i press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +  <kbd>R</kbd>  it reloads the `init.vim` file successfully and `echo`es in the vim command-line row that it worked.

`proof` that is working:

[image: proof]

but my problem is that the word `successfully` its not colored with `TerminalGreenColor`(`#6bd676`)...

any ideas? thanks in advance.

Comment: I copy pasted your code and it works for me with `NVIM v0.5.0` and `alacritty 0.8.0`. Have you tried another terminal emulator?

Comment: in the first place i used `xfce-terminal` (didnt work) and right now i tried in `alacritty` and it didnt work.

Comment: Hm... Looks like it will be hard to help you debug that then... What does `:verbose highlight TerminalGreenColor` say? And what happen if you run manually `:echohl TerminalGreenColor` then `:echo 'hello'`? Also have you tried changing the properties of `TerminalGreenColor` to have an idea if the issue comes from the highlighting group itself or from somewhere else?

Comment: `:verbose highlight TerminalGreenColor` ->  `TerminalGreenColor xxx cleared`

Comment: i tried printing the color directly in vim using :echohl, it worked. but i dont understand why it wouldnt from `init.vim`

Comment: Ah here is your problem: `:verbose highlight TerminalGreenColor` is supposed to say something like `TerminalGreenColor xxx guifg=#6bd676 Last set from ~/init.vim line XXX` here it looks like something cleared your highlighting group which is why you don't see color changes so you're up for [some debugging](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003)

Comment: my guess is, that sourcing your init.vim file clears up the highlighting. Perhaps because of a `:colorscheme command` or `:syntax` command

Comment: maybe it was cleared because i have `echohl None` before? but if dont put that still doesnt work.